# Error when Creating an Interactive Bar Chart with Plotly Express

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to create an interactive bar chart using Plotly Express to visualize the number of tasks starting and ending on the same day by title. However, I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. Here's a simplified version of my code and the sample data:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Sample task data
task_data = {
    'Task Title': ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4'],
    'Start Date': ['2023-09-16', '2023-09-16', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-18'],
    'End Date': ['2023-09-16', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-18'],
}

# Create a DataFrame
task_df = pd.DataFrame(task_data)

# Count the occurrences of each task title
task_counts = task_df['Task Title'].value_counts()

# Create an interactive bar chart
fig_task = px.bar(
    task_counts.reset_index(),
    x='index',  # Error occurs here
    y='Task Title',
    labels={'index': 'Task Title', 'Task Title': 'Count'},
    title='Tasks Starting and Ending on the Same Day by Title'
)

# Show the interactive bar chart
fig_task.show()
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['Task Title', 'count'] but received: index
To use the index, pass it in directly as `df.index`.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the name of the 'x' column you're trying to use (`'index'`) is not found in the DataFrame `task_counts.reset_index()`. When you reset the index on a pandas Series, the default name for the new column is `'index'`. However, the issue arises because `task_counts` is a Series and not a DataFrame, which means it's possible the column name assignment after resetting the index may differ from expectations.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

task_data = {
    'Task Title': ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4'],
    'Start Date': ['2023-09-16', '2023-09-16', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-18'],
    'End Date': ['2023-09-16', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-17', '2023-09-18'],
}

task_df = pd.DataFrame(task_data)

# Filter tasks that start and end on the same day
task_same_day = task_df[task_df['Start Date'] == task_df['End Date']]

# Count the occurrences of each task title for tasks that start and end on the same day
task_counts = task_same_day['Task Title'].value_counts()

# Reset the index and rename the columns
task_counts_df = task_counts.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Task Title', 'Task Title': 'Count'})

# Create your interactive bar chart
fig_task = px.bar(
    task_counts_df,
    x='Task Title',
    y='Count',
    labels={'Task Title': 'Task Title', 'Count': 'Count'},
    title='Tasks Starting and Ending on the Same Day by Title'
)

# Show your interactive bar chart
fig_task.show()
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the same error as the one shown above when I run your code.

Comment: That's weird it works for me